# How to copy files from the one folder to another if flag is True in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, copy, filenames, shutil

I have a dictionary having the bool values

```
test = {'db1': [{'url': 'http://localhost:8080/api', 'cmd': 'test\\nshow databases', 'flag': 'True'}], 
        'db2': [{'url': 'http://localhost:8080/api', 'cmd': 'test\\nshow databases', 'flag': 'False'}],
    'db3': [{'url': 'http://localhost:8080/api', 'cmd': 'test\\nshow databases', 'flag': 'True'}]}
```

there are 3 file inside the /home/ubuntu/ by name db1,db2,db3.

If the flag is True we need to move from

```
/home/ubuntu/db1 to /home/ubuntu/test/db1
/home/ubuntu/db3 to /home/ubuntu/test/db3
```

Normal way to copy using shutil, I have done . where to give flag condition

```
import shutil
import os
import glob
setupname = glob.glob("test1/*")
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("test1/"):
    for filename in files:
        print(filename)
        shutil.copy2(src, dest)
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to put the if statement at the top of the filename loop:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("test1/"):
    for filename in files:
        if test[filename][0]['flag'] == 'True':
            print(filename)
            shutil.copy2(src, dest)
```

Comment: just one querry. FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'db1...,
destination = "test2/"
filename = "test1/"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("test1/"):
    for filename in files:
        if test[filename][0]['flag'] == 'True':
            print(filename)
            shutil.copy2(filename, destination)

Comment: How to execute to from any folder. src that is filename is taking the current directory